# Micronaut - Kubernetes fails bean initialization

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to integrate K8 with my micronaut application. Here is my config. But I get this error . Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am trying to run my application locally, but connecting to remote K8 cluster.

Error:

```
17:09:18.120 [main] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.kubernetes.discovery.$KubernetesDiscoveryClientDefinition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
17:09:18.121 [main] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * None of the required environments [k8s] are active: []
```

Config :

```
kubernetes:
  client:
    host: remote-url
    port: 443
    secure: true
    namespace: default
    secrets:
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /kv/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes beans will only be loaded when the application is running within a Kubernetes cluster. If you care to elaborate your use case, we can revisit this restriction in an upcoming release.

Comment: ah! In a dev environemnt it becomes cumbersome to deploy the app into a kube cluster to test every small change.

Comment: Now I am running it inside a Kube cluster and get the following error. 

Error while trying to list all Kubernetes Services in the namespace [default]
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientException: Connect error:https

My host endpoint is https.

Comment: I've seen your issue report. Leaving a link here for reference: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kubernetes/issues/42. Also, for local development, you can try https://www.telepresence.io/